# Solving the dual problem of boosting using column generation

Tags: boosting

In our book there is boosting algorithm using column generation method (Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition) to solve the dual problem.
So lets say we have want to solve the following primal linear problem based on hinge loss:
$$\min_{w,\xi} \Sigma_{m=1}^Mw_m + C\Sigma_{i=1}^N\xi_i$$
$$ y_i\Sigma_{m=1}^MH_{im}w_m+\xi_i\geq 1 \text{ ,} i\in[N]$$
$$w,\xi \geq 0,$$

where $H_{im}:=\phi(x_i),i\in[N],m\in[M]$ and $C>0$ is a weighting factor.
Now the dual is:
$$\max_z \mathbb{1}^Tz$$
$$\Sigma_{i=1}^N y_i H_{im} z_i \leq 1 \text{ }, m\in[M]$$
$$0\leq z\leq C\mathbb{1}$$

Now in our book, it stated:

> The base learniners $\phi(x)$ can be obtained dynamically, by solving the dual problem with optimal solution $z^*\in\mathbb{R}_+^N$. For a given subset of base functions, we need to check whether there exists another function $\phi_m(x)$ such that the corresponding dual constraint is violated, i.e.,
> $$\Sigma_i=1^N y_iH_{im}z_i^* >1$$
> Thus the left hand side has to be maximized, which can be handled by calling  a base learner with weights $z^*$ trying to maximize the weighted number of points that are correctly classified. If the value is larger than 1, $\phi_m(x)$ is added to the set of base learners ant the process is repeated. Note that this process will terminate, since there are only finitely many vectors $H_{. m}\in{-1,+1}^N$.

**For me it is totally unclear why we are checking for functions $\phi_m(x)$ which violate the constraint.** I mean we want to solve the dual problem and if so the constraints forces us to use functions which classify the points incorrectly. Then we had $yH_m<0$ and the constraint would be active and the dual problem could be solved. I don't know how the problem is going to be solved if we only use functions which violate the constraint

Comment: Given that this is for boosting, it seems the functions which violate the constraint should be kept for next iteration of boosting